# InvalidOperationException in Memory Streams

Tags: c#, cloudinary, .net-core-2.2

I am trying to upload an image to cloudinary cloud. The file converts fine to memory stream but when I try to call upload method of cloudinary to upload the image, I get InvlalidOperationException. What I think is, there is something wrong with converting file to stream.[`See the image showing error`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R94wN.png)

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddPhotoForUser(int userId, [FromForm] AddPhotoDto addPhotoDto)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userId != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            var userFromRepo = await _datingRepository.GetUser(userId);

            var file = addPhotoDto.File;
            var uploadResult = new ImageUploadResult();

            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
                {
                    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                    {
                        File = new FileDescription(file.Name, stream),
                        Transformation = new Transformation()
                            .Width(500).Height(500).Crop("fill").Gravity("face")
                    };

                    uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
                }
            }

            addPhotoDto.Url = uploadResult.Url.ToString();
            addPhotoDto.PublicId = uploadResult.PublicId;

            var photo = _mapper.Map<Photo>(addPhotoDto);

            if (!userFromRepo.Photos.Any(p => p.IsMain))
            {
                photo.IsMain = true;
            }

            userFromRepo.Photos.Add(photo);
            if (await _datingRepository.SaveAll())
            {
                var photoToReturn = _mapper.Map<ReturnPhotoDto>(photo);
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetPhoto", new { id = photo.Id }, photoToReturn);
            }

            return BadRequest("Could not add photo");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: can u ensure that the `File.OpenReadStream().Read()` is ok ?     asp.net core do not like sync read/write

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: Avoid getting confused about what the **debugger** tells you about an object.  These are not runtime exceptions, just what happens when the debugger tries to display the properties of the stream.  MemoryStream does [not implement timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readtimeout?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Stream_ReadTimeout), it has no reason at all to do so.  Since the data is stored in memory.  Nothing to see there, keep going.

Comment: @Malik  I'm not familiar with the cloudinary , but  since you use `.Upload` without `await` , then I think it is not a async call , so  it is a sync read from your current request,  and asp.net core doesn't like sync read/write,  it may thorw  base on your setting(or default setting) for kestrel  ,  you can test that is it cause it by  using`file.OpenReadStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)` , you had to use `.CopyToAsync` to copy the stream to a buffered `MemoryStream`if it also thorw exception.  and if it not throw then ignore me, it not caused by this issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share why do you use open stream? You can try:

```
var imageuploadParams = new ImageUploadParams () {
                File = new FileDescription (@"https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1561532539/sample.jpg"),
                PublicId = "myimage",
                Transformation = new Transformation().Width(500).Height(500).Crop("fill").Gravity("face")
            };
            var ImageuploadResult = cloudinary.Upload (imageuploadParams);
```

Comment: I am sending image in the request that ia why can't give image path to FileDescription.